# Substation problem with a simple integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

i have this integral

$$ \int {4x\over \sqrt{1+4x^2}} dx  $$
and i have tried to solve it by doing like this $$ t=\sqrt{1+4x^2}->t^2=1+4x^2->2tdt=8xdx->tdt=4xdx $$ and im gettin this integral
$$  \int {tdt\over t} $$ here im getting the wrong answer
but when i input  $$ t=4x^2+1 $$
im getting the right answer
there should be no fragrance in in both whys,so what am i doing wrong

heres the original question
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$t=\sqrt{1+4x^2}\implies dt=\frac{8x\ dx}{2\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$$

$$\int\frac{4x}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}dx=\int dt=t+K=\sqrt{1+4x^2}+K$$

---

Alternatively, 
$t=1+4x^2\implies dt=8xdx$

$$\int\frac{4x}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}dx=\int\frac{dt}{2\sqrt t}=\sqrt t+C=\sqrt{1+4x^2}+C$$

Comment: @lab_bhattacharjee sorry it should be $$1+4x^2$$

Comment: @uberStyx0, Adjusted & added one more method

Comment: @uberStyx0, You should have posted the original QUestion, also answer may not always be correct. We can safely focus on the correctness of the methods, right answer will follow

Comment: @lab_bhattacharjee, the limits are between 0 and square root of 2
and i have pi outside the integral, but i do it on 1st method its aint getting right and in 2nd method it does(the answer is 8pi)

Comment: @ab_bhattacharjee, i added the original question(can you please solve it by changing to Polar coordinate system, thanks

Answer (score 1):

but calculating $\int 1dt$ i'm getting $\sqrt{1+4x^2}+C$ differentiating this we get the integrand

Comment: @Dr._Sonnhard_Graubner,  i added the original question(can you please solve it by changing to Polar coordinate system), thanks